# why prometheus using the rate to calculate the request_duration

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics

since the `request_duration` is just a counter, why we need to using the `rate` to calculate the duration, this is not meaningful.

```
histogram_quantile(0.99, sum by (le) (rate(server_request_duration_seconds_bucket[1m])))
```

suck as take example from: https://robert-scherbarth.medium.com/measure-request-duration-with-prometheus-and-golang-adc6f4ca05fe

Comment: the `rate` of duration has no meaning?

Comment: Your first statement is wrong. `server_request_duration_seconds_bucket` is an histogram, not a counter.

Answer (score 1):

The `server_request_duration_seconds` is a [histogram](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#histogram). It consists of multiple buckets with the name `server_request_duration_seconds_bucket` (the `_bucket` suffix is added to the original histogram name) with the upper boundary encoded in `le` label. Each such a bucket represents a counter, which counts the number of samples with values up to `le`. For example, `server_request_duration_seconds_bucket{le="0.5"}` counts the number of requests with the duration up to 0.5 seconds.

The `rate(server_request_duration_seconds_bucket[1m])` calculates the average per-second increase rate over the last minute individually per each bucket of `server_request_duration_seconds` histogram. E.g. the end result of `rate(...)` is a distribution of the increase rate of all the buckets over the last minute. This histogram can be exposed at multiple instances (aka replicas or shards) of a single service. So, if you want calculating the aggregate quantile over all these instances, you need to wrap the `rate()` into `sum() by (le)` before passing it to `histogram_quantile`.

The end result of the `histogram_quantile(0.9, sum(rate(server_request_duration_seconds_bucket[1m])) by (le))` is an estimated 99th percentile of `server_request_duration_seconds` histograms over the last minute, e.g. the maximum time in seconds needed for 99% of registered requests over the last minute.

Note that it is OK to use `increase` instead of `rate` when calculating the `histogram_quantile` - this shouldn't change the result, since `increase` returns the same distribution shape across buckets as `rate`.

P.S. `rate` and `increase` functions in Prometheus may return unexpected results because of extrapolation - see [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746). This may lead to less accurate results from `histogram_quantile`. If you experience this issue, then try VictoriaMetrics - this is a Prometheus-like monitoring system, which supports PromQL functionality via [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html). Contrary to Prometheus, it doesn't use extrapolation for `increase` and `rate` calculations, so it is free from issues related to the extrapolation. Prometheus developers are going to fix these issues too - see [this design doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y2Mp041_2v0blnKnZk7keCnJZICeK2YWUQuXH_m4DVc/edit).

P.P.S. I'm the core developer of VictoriaMetrics.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Prometheus documentation :

> rate(v range-vector) calculates the per-second average rate of increase of the time series in the range vector.
>
> [...]
>
> rate should only be used with counters. It is best suited for alerting, and for graphing of slow-moving counters.

It is only useful to get the "pace" or the frequency of evolution of a counter.

Example use case : get the requests per seconds rate based on the incoming request counter